# SQL Server track DDL CREATE USER

Tags: sql-server, triggers, ddl, ddl-trigger

I am trying to track user creation. I have looked at the DDL triggers in many posts but those seem only to track objects, not users. Is there a way for me to track/record when a user is created or deleted in SQL Server?

Answer (score 6):

[`CREATE_USER` is absolutely a trackable DDL event](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182669(v=sql.90).aspx), as is `DROP_USER`, and both have been since SQL Server 2005. [BOL is hard-pressed for decent examples, though](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186406(v=sql.90).aspx). The truth is the DDL trigger eventdata schema is not flexible enough to always have an entity named the way you want (like `UserName`). It's not intuitive, and may be the source of your confusion, but you actually need to pull the name of the created user from `ObjectName`:

```
USE [your_database_name];
GO

CREATE TRIGGER CatchUser
ON DATABASE
FOR CREATE_USER, DROP_USER
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @x XML = EVENTDATA();

  -- INSERT dbo.LoggingTable(Columns)
  SELECT 
    EventType = @x.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'nvarchar(256)'),
    UserName  = @x.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]','nvarchar(256)'),
    LoginName = @x.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'nvarchar(512)'),
    StartTime = @x.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/PostTime)[1]',  'datetime');
END
```

However, if you are just trying to audit this data after the fact, you can also pull this information from the default trace, if you poll frequently enough.

```
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(260);

SELECT @path = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([path]), 
   CHARINDEX(CHAR(92), REVERSE([path])), 260)) + N'log.trc'
FROM sys.traces WHERE is_default = 1;

SELECT EventType = CASE EventSubClass WHEN 3 THEN 'CREATE_USER'
  WHEN 4 THEN 'DROP_USER' END, TargetUserName, LoginName, StartTime
FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(@path, DEFAULT)
WHERE EventClass = 109 -- Create DB User Event
AND DatabaseName = N'your_database_name'
ORDER BY StartTime DESC;
```

This will get adds and drops, and you're supposed to be able to tell from the `EventSubClass` which event it was, but my experience is not matching with [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190250.aspx) - I get 3 for Add, 4 for Drop, but they say 1 is Add, 2 is Drop, 3 is grant access, and 4 is revoke access. *shrug*